# JavaScriptDeseializer : Can not serialize array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax

My application is asp.net. I have to send some values back to server. For this I create a object serialize it and send it to server. At server I try to de-serialize it
Following is my code

```
   [Serializable]
    public class PassData
    {
        public PassData()
        {  
        }

        public List<testWh> SelectedId { get; set; }

        public string SelectedControlClientId { get; set; }

        public string GroupTypeId { get; set; }

        public string SectionTypeId { get; set; }

  }


    [Serializable]
    public class testWh
    {
        public testWh()

        {
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }


JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//this can not serialize the SelectedId and the count remains 0
PassData data = serializer.Deserialize<PassData>(jsonString);
//this serialize in an anonymous object with key value pair
var data2 = serializer.DeserializeObject(textHiddenArguments.Text);
```

Following is my Json Serialized String

```
{
   "SelectedId":{"0":"ABCD","1":"JKLM"},
   "SelectedControlClientId":"YTUTOOO",
   "GroupTypeId":3,
   "SectionTypeId":"1"
}
```

quotes escaped string

```
"{\"SelectedId\":{\"0\":\"ABCD\",\"1\":\"JKLM\"},\"SelectedControlClientId\":\"YTUTOOO\",\"GroupTypeId\":3,\"SectionTypeId\":\"1\"}"
```

My Problem is Selected Id is array of testWH object. But when I try to desrialize it, the SelectedId property of PassData which is list does not get serialized and count remains zero.

I tried using array instead of List, which gave an exception "no parameter less constructor..."

Could any one explain the what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Not able to understand it. What do you mean by code-fields/field-initializers ?

Comment: ah, sorry - that was just my IDE add-in changing things when I pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem here is that the JSON doesn't match the objects you have constructed. You can see this by writing the data you want and serializing:

```
var obj = new PassData
{
    SelectedId = new List<testWh>
    {
        new testWh { Id = "ABCD"},
        new testWh { Id = "JKLM"}
    },
    GroupTypeId = "3",
    SectionTypeId = "1",
    SelectedControlClientId = "YTUTOOO"
};
string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

which gives JSON like:

```
{"SelectedId":[{"Id":"ABCD"},{"Id":"JKLM"}],
 "SelectedControlClientId":"YTUTOOO","GroupTypeId":"3","SectionTypeId":"1"}
```

So now you need to decide which you want to change; the JSON or the classes. The following alternative class works fine with your original JSON, for example:

```
public class PassData
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> SelectedId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedControlClientId { get; set; }
    public string GroupTypeId { get; set; }
    public string SectionTypeId { get; set; }
}
```